# Convergence of zeros of polynomials (/functions) as they converge pointwise to a polynomial(/function)

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, number-theory

The question that rose in my head is the following:
Let $(a^i_n)_{n\geq 0}$ for $i=0,\ldots, k$ be convergent sequences in $\mathbb{C}$, say $a^i_n\;  \to \; a^i$ as $n\, \to \, \infty$: consider the associated polynomials 
$$
p_n(z) =\sum_{i=0}^k a^i_n z^i
$$
Is it true that the zeros of $p_n$ in $\mathbb{C}$ converge to the zeros of $p(z)$ where 
$$
p(z) =\sum_{i=0}^k a^i z^i
$$
This is true for degree $\leq 2$ (if $a^2 \neq 0$) by considering the explicit formula for the solution, but I don't know how to proceed in the general case.

BONUS: are there general results for other type of functions (e.g. continuous) under additional assumptions?

Comment: this is called Hurwitz theorem and is true for normal convergence of analytic functions - here since the polynomials have bounded degrees $p_n \to p$ normally - (one has to be careful of boundary issues in general, but here or for entire functions in general the result is straightforward) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)